# How do I check if a number is contained in an array and get its index?

Tags: c#

If I enter the number 5, and it was at index 4 it will give me `not found` the first 3 times, and then the index will be the same as the number I entered.

```
int[] A = { 3, 6, 4, 9, 10, 1, 2, 8 };
int myNumber;
int length = A.Length;
Console.WriteLine("enter your number");
myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (myNumber == A[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the numer" + myNumber + "is present in the array at the index" +" "+ A[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the number you entered are not found");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: index is ``i`` not ``a[i]``

Answer (score 5):

The Array class has a nice IndexOf method you can use.  It'll return either the index location of the value you are looking for, or it'll return a -1 if the value is not found.

```
int[] A = { 3, 6, 4, 9, 10, 1, 2, 8 };

Console.WriteLine("enter your number");
int myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int indexLocation = Array.IndexOf(A, myNumber);
if (indexLocation > -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number {0} was found at index location {1}", myNumber, indexLocation);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number {0} was not found", myNumber);
}
```

Comment: It should be `Array.IndexOf(A, myNumber);`. The problem is that while it is technically correct (and the best way to solve it), it isn't "formative". It is a "Here take the magic function that solves all your problems", while her problems where of comprehension of how to exit from a for cycle.

Comment: @xanatos: But that's not what she asked. By all means edit the question text and title to make that the question.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier that would be my mistake, trying to formulate the question title to match what she was trying to achieve.

Comment: @xanatos I'm been back and forth on this one.  I've answered questions like you're talking about, modifying the OP's code as little as possible.  Then another answer will get selected and it's almost a complete rewrite from the OP's code.

Comment: @xanatos: One of the key points in software development is to avoid reinventing the wheel. 95% of questions/issues or maybe even more arise from people unable to research what was already invented before they start making theirs. One may argue that reinventing the wheel is a good exercise for the brain. Trust me, there are better exercises than reinventing how `IndexOf` works.

Comment: @Neolisk I do think that there are two lessons that the questioner can learn: how to write an `IndexOf` and that there is a pre-defined `IndexOf`. Both are very important. I'll say that the first one is more important, because it's important to know how the instruments are built, because the alternative is coming here and asking why your `IQueryable` expression throw a `NotSupportedException`, or why `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.23`

Comment: @xanatos I completely agree with you

Comment: @xanatos: Knowing how to write an efficient IndexOf is arguably important. There are other much more complicated concerns in software development. Patterns, architecture etc. You can learn how all functions in .NET are written, but you will fail to maintain a complex enterprise application. What's the use of such a developer then? I'm saying all this because I used to be like you, trying to learn how everything is built, and guess what - most of my knowledge is now useless in professional software development.

Answer (score 1):

The correct program:

```
int[] A = { 3, 6, 4, 9, 10, 1, 2, 8 };
int myNumber;
int length = A.Length;
Console.WriteLine("enter your number");
myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

// ADDED
bool found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (myNumber == A[i])
    {
        found = true; // ADDED
        // On the far right of next row: Fixed A[i] -> i
        Console.WriteLine("the numer" + myNumber + "is present in the array at the index" + " " + i); 
        break;
    }
}

// ADDED
if (!found)
{
    Console.WriteLine("the number you entered are not found");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

I hope/think you can see/comprehend the differences without help.

I'll add that there is a second method to solve the problem:

```
int[] A = { 3, 6, 4, 9, 10, 1, 2, 8 };
int myNumber;
int length = A.Length;
Console.WriteLine("enter your number");
myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

// MOVED OUTSIDE FOR
int i = 0;

for (; i < length; i++)
{
    if (myNumber == A[i])
    {
        // On the far right of next row: Fixed A[i] -> i
        Console.WriteLine("the numer" + myNumber + "is present in the array at the index" + " " + i);
        break;
    }
}

// ADDED
if (i == length)
{
    Console.WriteLine("the number you entered are not found");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

See the difference: `found` isn't necessary and we use only the `i` variable, that has its "scope" expanded.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your code to something like this. Your first mistake was to print A[i] instead of i, your second mistake was to print the not found message inside the loop. If you move it outside the loop it will be printed only once, same applies to Console.ReadKey()

```
 int[] A = { 3, 6, 4, 9, 10, 1, 2, 8 };
    int myNumber;
    int length = A.Length;
    Console.WriteLine("enter your number");
    myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    bool isFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (myNumber == A[i])
        {

            Console.WriteLine("the numer" + myNumber + "is present in the array at the index" +" "+ i);

            isFound = true;
        }          
    }

   if (!isFound)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("the number you entered are not found");
   }

   Console.ReadKey();

}
```

}